Extract concrete type from generic discriminated union
I'm trying to extract a response type from a pair of request/response based on request type only.
I want to correlate two types, request and response and return a response type based on the request type.
The issue that I currently have it's with the handleRequest function and I think the Extract type it's not norrowing the generic type correctly.
interface AbstractWorkerRequest {
  id: string
  type: string
}
interface AbstractWorkerResponse {
  id: string
  type: string
}
type WorkerExchange<REQUEST extends AbstractWorkerRequest, RESPONSE extends AbstractWorkerResponse> = {
    type: REQUEST['type']
    response: RESPONSE
    request: REQUEST
}

Now I have two types of request/responses pairs:
type InitRequest = AbstractWorkerRequest & {
  type: 'init'
  body: number
}
type InitResponse = AbstractWorkerResponse & {
  type: 'init'
  body: { id: number }
}
type InitRequest2 = AbstractWorkerRequest & {
  type: 'init2'
  body: number
}
type InitResponse2 = AbstractWorkerResponse & {
  type: 'init2'
  body: { test: number }
}
type Exchanges = WorkerExchange<InitRequest, InitResponse> | WorkerExchange<InitRequest2, InitResponse2>
type AnyRequest = Exchanges['request']
type AnyResponse = Exchanges['response']

And I want to extract the response based only on the request type using:
type TypeOfResponse<T extends AnyRequest> = Extract<AnyResponse, { type: T['type'] }> // I think the issue is here, but don't know how to handle it
function clientCode() {
    const request: InitRequest = {
        id: '',
        type: 'init',
        body: -1
    }
    const result = createPromise(request)// result should be of type InitResult
    console.log(result.body.id)
}
function createPromise<T extends AnyRequest>(request: T): TypeOfResponse<T> {
    const result = handleRequest(request)
    return result
}

function handleRequest<T extends AnyRequest>(request: T): TypeOfResponse<T> {
    switch(request.type) {
        case "init": {
            const results: TypeOfResponse<InitRequest> = {
                id: '',
                type: 'init',
                body: { id: -1 },
            }
            return results // Type 'InitResponse' is not assignable to type 'Extract<InitResponse2, { type: T["type"]; }>'
        }
        case 'init2': {
            const results: InitResponse2 = {
                id: '',
                type: 'init2',
                body: { test: -1 }
            }
            return results // Type 'InitResponse2' is not assignable to type 'Extract<InitResponse2, { type: T["type"]; }>'.
        }
    }
}

It's possible to extract the response type from the AnyRequest type somehow without chaning the createPromise and the clientCode?
Maybe this playground helps.

The sort of thing you're doing is only supported via generic indexed accesses as described in ms/TS#47109. The recommended refactoring looks like this playground link, which doesn't change the runtime behavior of createPromise and clientCode, but necessarily rewrites the types. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

That's exactly what I was trying to achieve, I can adjust the typings as needed
